# Vaadin grid, how to header wrap caption

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

In Vaadin 7, how do you wrap the caption in the grid header?  Right now the column is much wider then it needs to be based on the expected data, so the users want the column heading wrapped.

I tried the following:

```
.v-grid-column-header-content .v-grid-column-default-header-content {
    white-space: normal;
  }
```

but the browser cannot even see this change, so I am probably using the wrong CSS selectors.  I have tried quite a few different selectors based on what I am seeing in the browser and the [documentation](https://origin.vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-grid), and none seem to work.  I know it doesn't work because when I make the column narrower by dragging it, and it does not wrap.  When I added `white-space: normal;` directly in browser, it wrapped correctly.

Also, I cleared the browser cache every time to ensure that was not the issue.

The next issue will be making the row automatically tall enough for the wrapping to be meaningful.  So if you have ideas on this topic, please offer them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not officially supported feature in Vaadin 7 Grid, but there is header wrap extension in [GridExtensionPack](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gridextensionpack-add-on) add-on. that you can use.

Note, in modern Vaadin versions such as 14, 23 or 24 this is trivially supported.

Comment: Yep, I expected Vaadin 14+ would be better.  Anyway, GridExtensionPack mostly works.  It looks like I will need to manually set Column widths to "trigger" wrapping.  Even when I force a recalculation of the column widths with `grid.recalculateColumnWidths();`, it won't make columns smaller to trigger wrapping.  Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: According to [source](https://github.com/tsuoanttila/GridExtensionPack/blob/1.0/GridExtensionPack-demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/teemusa/gridextensions/demo/HeaderWrapExtensionLayout.java), I might not have to set the widths.  Maybe it has something to do with loading the grid using `container.addAll` instead of `grid.addRow`?  Also doesn't wrap on the initial load of `Grid`, only after the initial load.  Weird.  For now, disabling wrapping and column widths before loading Grid, then turning back on when finish.  Not ideal, but works.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it mostly works, but for anyone else that finds this: there are many problems.  Basically, I have to disable wrapping and set column widths undefined before loading grid container, then set wrapping back on, with column widths, after, and even that does not work perfectly.  Even in demo mentioned above, it makes them turn on wrapping with a button.  So I think the problem is that things need to be done after Grid totally loaded and displayed on screen (NOT attached, displayed).  Will ask this as a separate question.